# Error: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, mysql, django

i have a problem with Django:
I can't show the data from mysql database in the table. I see the error "Exception Value: unhashable type: 'dict'"
This is my code:
views.py:

```
List_of_date=El.objects.all()
return HttpResponse(template.render(context),args, {'List_of_date': List_of_date})
```

models.py:

```
class El(models.Model):
    id_ch=models.IntegerField()
    TXT = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>№</th>
        <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   {% for i in List_of_date %}
    <tr>
        <td class="center">{{ i.id_ch }}</td>
        <td class="center">{{ i.TXT }}</td>
    </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you please give us the full traceback of that error message.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing bad arguments to HttpResponse constructor
signature is

```
HttpResponse.__init__(content='', content_type=None, status=200, reason=None, charset=None)
```

and I thinks you want to use `{'List_of_date': List_of_date}` as context for template render.
So you rather want call something like (i don't know what menas your args variable)

```
return HttpResponse(template.render(Context({'List_of_date': List_of_date})))
```

Comment: But actually op should be using the render shortcut anyway.

Comment: I use the variable "args"  like a  dictionary of terms
 args={}
 args['username']=auth.get_user(request).username
 args['SheduleElectForm']='true'                   
 template = loader.get_template('template.html')
When i write:
"return HttpResponse(template.render(Context({'List_of_date': List_of_date})))" i see the error "'RequestContext' object is not callable"

Comment: *Please*, just use the `render` shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

**When do you generally get an `unhashable type: 'dict'` error?**

When you try to use a dictionary as a key to perform lookup in another dictionary, you get this error.

For example:

```
In [1]: d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}

In [2]: d2 = {'c':3}

In [3]: d2[d1] # perform lookup with key as dictionary 'd1'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-163d2a314f4b> in <module>()
----> 1 d2[d1]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

**Why are getting this error?**

This is because you have passed wrong arguments to `HttpResponse` class when creating its instance as pointed out by [@Francis.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838984/farincz)

When you do `HttpResponse(template.render(context), args, {'List_of_date': List_of_date})`, then `template.render(context)` becomes `content`, `args` becomes the `content_type` and the dictionary `{'List_of_date': List_of_date}` becomes the `status` of the response object.

Now internally, Django performs a lookup based on the `status` of the response object to set the `reason_phrase` on response object. **Since the `status` is not an integer but a dictionary, the above error occurs.**

**Solution:**

You need to use [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut provided by Django instead as [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) also mentioned which is perfect for what you are intending to do.

It will render the template for you and automatically render the template with `RequestContext` instance. You can do something like:

```
return render(template_name, {'List_of_date': List_of_date})
```